# Android calling jni method from thread Error(A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 13620 (AsyncTask #3))

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-ndk

I want to do some work with ndk for security problem.

`my ndk code:`

```
jbyte * buff;
jbyte * result;

jint buff_size = 0;
jint result_size = 0;


jbyte * key = (jbyte *)"HashCode";
jint key_size = 9;

jbyte* ramz(jbyte* s ,jint size_s, jbyte* k, jint size_k)
{
    return s;
}

jbyte* dramz(jbyte* s ,jint size_s, jbyte* k, jint size_k)
{
    return s;
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_shabaviz_Server_Server_clear(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "start of clear\n");
    if (buff_size > 0)
    {
        delete[] buff;
    }
    buff = new jbyte[0];
    buff_size = 0;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "end of clear\n");
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_shabaviz_Server_Server_addChar(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj, jbyte c_int) {
    jbyte *temp = new jbyte[buff_size+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < buff_size; ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = buff[i];
    }

    temp[buff_size] = c_int;
    jbyte * oldbuf = buff;
    buff =  temp;
    delete[] oldbuf;
    ++buff_size;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_shabaviz_Server_Server_ramz(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "start of ramz\n");
    if (result_size > 0)
    {
        delete[] result;
    }

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "ramzOOOO\n");
    result = ramz(buff, buff_size , key , key_size);
    result_size = buff_size;// + 7;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "end of ramz\n");
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_shabaviz_Server_Server_dramz(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "start of dramz\n");
    if (result_size > 0)
    {
        delete[] result;
    }

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "dramzOOOO\n");
    result = dramz(buff, buff_size , key , key_size);
    result_size = buff_size;// - 7;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "end of dramz\n");
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_shabaviz_Server_Server_sizeOf(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "start/end of sizeOf\n");
    return result_size;

}

JNIEXPORT jbyte JNICALL Java_com_shabaviz_Server_Server_getChar(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj, jint c_int) {
    return  result[c_int];

}
```

`my java code structure`

`com.shabaviz.Server.Server.java`

```
public class Server {

    static{

        System.loadLibrary("hellondk");
    }


    public synchronized static String sendPost(String url , String json) throws Exception {

        .
        .
        .

        byte [] data = newramz(json.getBytes());
        .
        .
        .
        return new String(newdramz(responseFromServer));
    }

    public native static void ramz();
    public native static void dramz();
    public native static void clear();
    public native static void addChar(byte c);
    public native static int sizeOf();
    public native static byte getChar(int index);


    public synchronized static byte[] newramz(byte[] s)
    {
        clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; ++i)
        {
            addChar(s[i]);
        }
        ramz();

        byte[] enc = new byte[sizeOf()];

        for (int i = 0; i < enc.length; ++i)
        {
            enc[i] = getChar(i);
        }
        return enc;
    }

    public synchronized static byte[] newdramz(byte[] s)
    {
        clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; ++i)
        {
            addChar(s[i]);
        }
        dramz();

        byte[] dec = new byte[sizeOf()];

        for (int i = 0; i < dec.length; ++i)
        {
            dec[i] = getChar(i);
        }

        return dec;
    }
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    .
    .
    .
    public class Login extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
        .
        .
        .

         protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            response = Server.sendPost(url1 , jsonString1);
            .
            .
            .
            response2 = Server.sendPost(url2 , jsonString2);
         }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

`And my problem:`

when i android Application I see force close with below logcat.

> 08-30 14:46:33.604 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: start of clear
>   08-30 14:46:33.604 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: end of clear
>   08-30 14:46:33.604 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: start of ramz
>   08-30 14:46:33.604 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: ramzOOOO
>   08-30 14:46:33.604 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: end of ramz
>   08-30 14:46:33.604 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: start/end of sizeOf
>   08-30 14:46:33.693 15394-15394/com.shabaviz.telegram D/mehdi: oncreatMainActivity
>     08-30 14:46:33.751 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: start of clear
>   08-30 14:46:33.751 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: end of clear
>   08-30 14:46:33.852 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: start of dramz
>   08-30 14:46:33.857 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: dramzOOOO
>   08-30 14:46:33.857 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: end of dramz
>   08-30 14:46:33.857 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: start/end of sizeOf
>   08-30 14:46:33.868 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: start of clear
>   08-30 14:46:33.868 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: end of clear
>   08-30 14:46:33.869 15394-15470/com.shabaviz.telegram V/telegramNDK: start of ramz
>   08-30 14:25:31.700 24282-24486/com.shabaviz.telegram A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb9436fa8 passed to dlfree
>   08-30 14:25:31.701 24282-24486/com.shabaviz.telegram A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 24486 (AsyncTask #3)

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what will happen when you call `ramz`/`dramz`, add some characters, followed by `clear`, followed by `ramz`/`dramz` again:

Upon the first call to `ramz`/`dramz` you set `result = buff`, i.e. `result` points to the same chunk of memory as `buff`. And you set `result_size` to a value greater than zero.
When you call `clear`, `buff_size` will be >0 so you'll `delete[] buff` (which is the same memory that `result` points to).
Then you call `ramz`/`dramz` again, which will attempt to do `delete[] result`, but that memory has already been freed => OOPS.

---

As a side note, that `addChar` method is *really* inefficient. You're doing a new allocation for every character and copying the old contents to the new buffer, instead of e.g. doubling the size of the buffer when it becomes full. And of course, instead of passing the characters one-by-one in a loop you could pass the entire `byte[]` at once.